# Debugging Regular Expression

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write an injector for C++ source files in java. It's just a basic tool to speed up the code editing process.

What I am scanning for is basically:

```
ClassName::FunctionName() {
```

I used txt2re (http://txt2re.com) to generate a regular expression for my search which equals:

```
.*?(?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*).*?((?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*))(:)(:)((?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*))(\\().*?(\\)).*?(\\{)
```

My application was written in Java and worked on my test file. Now I tried to scan subdirectories of source code with it to apply my changes but the matcher hangs. It is said that some regular expressions are not optimized or even wrong so it makes sense to hang. I'm not an expert when it comes to regular expressions and not very firm using them (it happens very seldom). Is there any way to speed up the matching process or correct my pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Your search is grouping features for extraction into a replacement expression. Do you need that? I assume you do. I removed the empty alternatives (i.e. ":?") which you don't need, and flattened the groupings. If all you want to do is inject some code after you identify a matching line, it can be flattened even further. Here's some code I modified from txt2re:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String txt=" ClassName::function_name123(char *p)  { ";

    String re1="([a-z][a-z0-9_]*)";    // match and group class name
    String re2="::";   // match and eat exactly ::
    String re3="([a-z][a-z0-9_]*)";    // match and group function name
    String re4="(\\(.*\\))";   // match and group round braces (and any parameters between them)
    String re5="\\s*"; // match and eat whitespace
    String re6="\\{";  // match and eat exactly {

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5+re6,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(txt);
    if (m.find())
    {
        String classname=m.group(1);
        String funcname=m.group(2);
        String params=m.group(3);
        System.out.println("I discovered that class "+classname+" has function "+funcname+params);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried your regex and it terminates much faster in the problematic file now but not all occurences are found! Altough I'm not sure why...

Comment: to quote a difference my basic function outline looks like: `void ClassName::FunctionName(void *arg, ...)\n{` But that shouldn't make a difference

Comment: If the expression you want to match is over several lines of the file, (evidenced by the newline before your opening brace), then you need to make sure that you concatenate those lines before doing regexp matching. Otherwise you will be doing matching on  "void ClassName::function_name123(void *arg, ... )" (which does not match), followed by matching on "{" (which also does not match.

Comment: Could you enter a few examples of occurrences that you want to match but that weren't matched?

Comment: I think that the newlines really make a problem but I cannot see any difference between the function definitions. It's only a differnt name. It does match with my regex but stall and does not match with yours `void CMyClass::DoStuff(IStartApp *startApp,void *obj) \n {`

Comment: When I replace the definition of txt above with the line `String txt=" void CMyClass::DoStuff(IStartApp *startApp,void *obj) \n {";` it matches it fine.